# Calling Oracle Stored Procedure from Java Web application

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

I am trying to call several oracle stored procedures from my web application. There are no in or out parameters in any of the procedures.   Everything works perfectly when I run my web app locally, but when I deploy the app to our test server the stored procedure calls stop working.   I get no error messages and the procedure does not run.

I would think it has something to do with the JDBC driver or connection, but I'm at a loss?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code that works perfectly when running locally and debugging:

```
public boolean deleteFromTempTables(String id)
{
    String msg = "";
    CallableStatement stmt1 = null;
    
    try
    {
       conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
       
       DbmsOutput dbmsOutput = new DbmsOutput( conn );

       dbmsOutput.enable( 1000000 );
       
       stmt1 = conn.prepareCall("{call delete_from_temp_employee()}");
       stmt1.execute();
       stmt1.close();
       
       dbmsOutput.show(id);

       dbmsOutput.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            stmt1.close();
            conn.close();

        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure delete_from_temp_employee as 
temp_empe_before NUMBER;
temp_empe_after  NUMBER;

begin

    select count(*) into temp_empe_before from temp_employee;
    delete from temp_employee;
    select count(*) into temp_empe_after from temp_employee;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Procedure DELETE_FROM_TEMP_EMPLOYEE Employee Before:  ' || temp_empe_before);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Procedure DELETE_FROM_TEMP_EMPLOYEE Employee After:  ' || temp_empe_after);

end delete_from_temp_employee;
```

Call in JSP page:

```
<%

boolean isDeleteError = false; 
isDeleteError = memberupload.deleteFromTempTables(userid);

%>
```

Comment: Anything in the log?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the server log.

Comment: You need better error handling so you can see the exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute:

```
set serveroutput ON;
```

this command makes output works.

also after delete statement add `commit;` command to commit changes if you forget it.

by the way, you can get the affected rows for DML statements like delete statement by using sql%rowcownt as following:

```
set serveroutput ON;
create or replace procedure delete_from_temp_employee2 as 
 rows NUMBER; 
begin

  delete from temp_employee;
  rows := SQL%rowcount; 


  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Deleted: ' || rows || ' row(s)'); 

end delete_from_temp_employee2;
```